# Where can I find simple_spinner_item in AndroidX?

Tags: android, android-spinner, androidx

I'm using in my app an ArrayAdapter who is initialized like so:

```
myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    myList
);
```

Where can I find the correspondent of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` in AndroidX package?

Comment: There isn't one, really. It's just a `<TextView>`. However, the `LayoutInflater` that `AppCompatActivity` uses will automatically substitute an `AppCompatTextView` for that `TextView`.

Comment: That is, you can just keep using `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`, if you like. If you want to customize it, you can create your own layout.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MikeM. I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In Android Studio) If you right click on it and choose to go to Declaration you'll find the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
    /* //device/apps/common/assets/res/any/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml
    **
    ** Copyright 2006, The Android Open Source Project
    **
    ** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
    ** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
    ** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
    **
    **     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
    **
    ** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
    ** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
    ** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
    ** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
    ** limitations under the License.
    */
    -->
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

**EDIT after comments:**

[simple_spinner_item was added on API 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout#simple_spinner_item) so it is supported by all versions of Android. AndroidX came as a continuation of the support libraries for features that were added in more recent APIs and needed backward compatibility. In this case, it doesn't affect the use of this particular layout as it's available in all versions. You can carry on using it. I'll leave the contents of the layout as above just in case you want to override the style and customise it as it's mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: Thanks for answering me but can you please also provide that in code?

Comment: @Jorn Maybe I misunderstood your question. Are you looking for the location of the file? What code are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to find the corresponding resource id like this `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`, so it can be passed to the ArrayAdapter constructor.

Comment: @Jorn corresponding to what? Why can't you use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item as it is?

Comment: I thought I need to use the corresponding `simple_spinner_item` that exist in AndroidX. Is it ok to continue using it?

Comment: @Jorn I see. You can carry on using it, it's the same!

Comment: Thank you Nikos, I'm ok now.

Answer (score 2):

All the layouts are located in: sdk\platforms\android-xx\data\res\layout
To view the XML of layout :

**Eclipse**: Simply type `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` somewhere in code, hold Ctrl, hover over `simple_spinner_item`, and from the dropdown that appears select "Open declaration in `layout/simple_spinner_item.xml`". It'll direct you to the contents of the XML.

**Android Studio:** Project Window -> External Libraries -> Android X Platform -> res -> layout, and here you will see a list of available layouts.

[image]